# WebLogic deployment succeed with errors

Tags: java, weblogic12c, bean-validation, dtd

we are upgrading our WebLogic 10 which runs on java 6 to WebLogic 12C which runs on java 8.

initially I couldn't deploy my application on WebLogic 12C. I figured, using following command, that I should update couple of **ejb-jar.xml** files in my "WEB_APPLICATION".ear file to overcome the validation errors.

> java weblogic.DDConverter -d . "WEB_APPLICATION".ear

precisely saying, I have updated all **"message-driven-destination"** tags to be compatible with the new version of java and WebLogic. For example, one of my **ejb-jar.xml** files looks like bellow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.2">
    <display-name>CacheNotificationsMDBeanModule</display-name>
    <enterprise-beans>
    <message-driven>
      <description>Message driven bean for cache notifications</description>
      <display-name>CacheNotificationsMDB</display-name>
      <ejb-name>CacheNotificationsMDB</ejb-name>
      <ejb-class>com.cache.CacheNotificationsMDB</ejb-class>
      <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>   
      <activation-config>
        <activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property-name>destinationType</activation-config-property-name>
          <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Topic</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property-name>subscription-durability</activation-config-property-name>
          <activation-config-property-value>NonDurable</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
      </activation-config>    
    </message-driven>
    </enterprise-beans>
    <assembly-descriptor>
    <container-transaction>
      <method>
        <ejb-name>CacheNotificationsMDB</ejb-name>
        <method-name>*</method-name>
      </method>
      <trans-attribute>NotSupported</trans-attribute>
    </container-transaction>
    </assembly-descriptor>
</ejb-jar>
```

Although I can deploy my application now, I get following messages and errors.

> <**********> <******> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '19'
>   for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <> <>
>   <37954930-b27e-4d11-86e2-87dc139d7fda-00000012> <1535573307036>
>   <[severity-value: 16] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name:
>   DOMAIN] >  , EJBComponent:
>   common-utils-mdbs.jar) is configured with unknown
>   activation-config-property name subscription-durability>
>
> <**********> <******> <[STANDBY]
>   ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'>
>    <> <37954930-b27e-4d11-86e2-87dc139d7fda-00000007>
>   <1535573336247> <[severity-value: 16] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0]
>   [partition-name: DOMAIN] >  /kuy712/war/WEB-INF/validation.xml, does not conform to the JSR 303 specifications.>
>
> <**********> <******> <[STANDBY] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue:
>   'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'>  <>
>   <37954930-b27e-4d11-86e2-87dc139d7fda-00000007> <1535573336243>
>   <[severity-value: 32] [rid: 0] [partition-id: 0] [partition-name:
>   DOMAIN] >

the **validation.xml** file, in the specified directory, looks like bellow

```
<!DOCTYPE form-validation PUBLIC
          "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Commons Validator Rules Configuration 1.1//EN"
          "dtds/validator_1_1_3.dtd">
<form-validation>

  <!--  Default locale validation -->

  <!--  Some of the example validation in the default formset are diabled for now,
    but can be enabled and customized as needed
    for your default and other formsets formset. Note that http://www.regexlib.com/ may
    contain usefull regular expressions to apply to your customization
    with the "mask" validator! -->
  <formset>
    .......
```

and **validator_1_1_3.dtd** file exist in follwoing directory.

> /u01/app/oracle/config/domains/Domainlab/servers/********/tmp/_WL_user//kuy712/war/WEB-INF/dtds

I am new to weblogic and am not quite sure how to fix this issue. can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 1):

Your ejb-jar.xml should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.2">
    <display-name>CacheNotificationsMDBeanModule</display-name>
    <enterprise-beans>
    <message-driven>
      <description>Message driven bean for cache notifications</description>
      <display-name>CacheNotificationsMDB</display-name>
      <ejb-name>CacheNotificationsMDB</ejb-name>
      <ejb-class>com.cache.CacheNotificationsMDB</ejb-class>
      <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type>   
      <activation-config>
        <activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property-name>destinationType</activation-config-property-name>
          <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Topic</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property-name>subscriptionDurability</activation-config-property-name>
          <activation-config-property-value>NonDurable</activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
      </activation-config>    
    </message-driven>
    </enterprise-beans>
    <assembly-descriptor>
    <container-transaction>
      <method>
        <ejb-name>CacheNotificationsMDB</ejb-name>
        <method-name>*</method-name>
      </method>
      <trans-attribute>NotSupported</trans-attribute>
    </container-transaction>
    </assembly-descriptor>
</ejb-jar>
```

Allowed properties names are: acknowledgeMode, messageSelector, destinationType, subscriptionDurability, destinationLookup, connectionFactoryLookup, subscriptionName and clientId. subscription-durability is not allowed.

Comment: Thank you Saxon! It solved one of my issues. Still struggling with lots of others though.